# Python on my Mac is broken; How do I start from scratch?

Tags: macos, python

After updating to Lion a few months ago, I noticed that any Python-based apps/tools stopped working. After some research, I solved the problem by re-installing the official Python installer, and correcting my PATH variable.

Now though, I'm not so sure everything is working the way it should, because when I try to use Sublime Text 2, I get an error report dialog with:

```
....

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
Referenced from: /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
Reason: image not found

....
```

Upon inspection, my `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6` folder contains:

```
2.6/
  Extras/
  Headers/ --(symlink)--> include
  include/
  lib/
```

Not `Python` like expected.

Curious, I did a little digging, and find that I have

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/Developer-3.2.6/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/Developer-3.2.6/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Along with several application-specific distributions, but I'm not concerned about those.

Am I supposed to have Python frameworks in *both* `/Library/Frameworks` and `/System/Library/Frameworks`? What's the difference between the two?

At this point, I feel like things would just be cleaner to start from scratch with Python, but how can I do that without screwing up my existing tools/apps? Would I need to delete my Python frameworks? Should I use the official installer, or perhaps homebrew's `python` package?

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard python, that comes with Lion, is python 2.7.

Your best chance to get the default setup is probably to copy the relevant files from a different Lion install on a friends machine.

I took a quick look at my Lion System and this is how my pyhton install looks like:

```
ls -lah /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/

total 2296
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel   374B Aug 18 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel   238B Jul 11  2011 ..
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   204B Jul 11  2011 Extras
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    17B Aug 18 15:20 Headers -> include/python2.7
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B Jun 17  2011 Mac
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   2.7M Jul 11  2011 Python
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel   238B Jul 11  2011 Resources
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B Jun 17  2011 _CodeSignature
drwxr-xr-x  17 root  wheel   578B Jul 11  2011 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B Jun 17  2011 include
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B Jul 11  2011 lib
```

And:

```
ls -lah /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel   170B Jul 11  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x   11 root  wheel   374B Aug 18 15:22 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     9B Jul 11  2011 libpython2.7.dylib -> ../Python
drwxr-xr-x    4 root  wheel   136B Jul 11  2011 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x  643 root  wheel    21K Oct 14 08:46 python2.7
```

And /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ contains all the stuff in the python standard lib like for example:

```
total 13672
drwxr-xr-x   643 root  wheel    21K Oct 14 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x     5 root  wheel   170B Jul 11  2011 ..
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    22K Jun 17  2011 BaseHTTPServer.py
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    22K Jul 11  2011 BaseHTTPServer.pyc
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    22K Jul 11  2011 BaseHTTPServer.pyo
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel   5.6K Jun 17  2011 Bastion.py
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel   7.2K Jul 11  2011 Bastion.pyc
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel   7.2K Jul 11  2011 Bastion.pyo
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    13K Jun 17  2011 CGIHTTPServer.py
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    11K Jul 11  2011 CGIHTTPServer.pyc
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    11K Jul 11  2011 CGIHTTPServer.pyo
-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel    26K Jun 17  2011 ConfigParser.py
....
```